# Implementation in C language with notesapi 9.01 in Red Hat Enterprise 6.x environment

Tags: c, lotus-notes, lotus-designer

I have a problem with implementation in C language using notesapi 9.01 in Red Hat Enterprise 6.x. I have code (IBM Examples) that normally runs on Windows and AIX, but when I run the same code on RedHat, appears the error 'Segment Failure'. What can be?
I use GCC as compiler.

Comment: Show the source code

Comment: Follows the link for files: https://www.dropbox.com/s/4rho3jlbywhilgt/c-sample-ibm.zip?dl=0

Comment: remembering that I use the noteapi 9.01. Follows the api: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2ahuj7s6xfa7350/C_API_TKT_NOTDOM_901AIXEN.tar.z?dl=0

Comment: In my environment I'm using:

- Suse enterprise linux 11 x86/64
- IBM Domino 9.01 64bit
- GCC 4.3x
- Notes api for domino 9.01

Comment: When does the error occur? During compilation, or during a test run of your code?

Comment: During test. On SUSE Enterprise Server 11 64BIT worked when I ran by the path: /opt/lotus/data the sample code 'FindByKeyExtend', but on Red Hat Enterprise Server 6.6 64BIT appears the follow error message: 'Unable to initialize Notes.'

Comment: I'm using SUSE for build/compile and Red Hat for execute. My production environment is in Red Hat Enterprise 6.6

Comment: I did a procedure that solved the problem. Daniel Nashed (http://blog.nashcom.de/) give me a solution:

Comment: Follows the solution: when you build the example correctly and it has no errors, the binary should not be the issue. how do you run it? you need to properly copy it to the server binary directory and create a start link. it should be in '/opt/ibm/domino/notes/latest/linux' and in '/opt/ibm/domino/bin' you need a link for your binary 'ln -s tools/startup yourbinaryname' than switch to the data directory 'cd /local/notesdata' and run it from there...